# Infinite loop by using @Binding when passing data between views

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationstack

#### High-level description:

There is a nested view problem when a state object is being passed through views. At the end of the deepest view in the hierarchy, the app is frozen and memory consumption is increasing continuously.

#### Use-case

Partners list → Partner detail → (Locations list) → Location detail

#### Code-snippets

```swift
class PartnerViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var partners: [Partner] = Partner.partners
}
```

This view is loaded into a `TabView` and a `NavigationStack` components in the parent class.

```swift
struct PartnerListView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = PartnerViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        List($viewModel.partners, id: \.self) { $partner in
            NavigationLink {
                PartnerDetailView(partner: $partner)
            } label: {
                Text(partner.name)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
struct PartnerDetailView: View {
    @Binding var partner: Partner

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section("Locations") {
                List($partner.locations, id: \.self) { $location in
                    NavigationLink {
                        LocationDetailView(location: $location)
                    } label: {
                        Text(location.name)
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

```swift
struct LocationDetailView: View {
    @Binding var location: Location
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Name", text: $location.name)
    }
}
```

The following snippets are workaround and it works but it might be temporary because I don't understand why the first attempt doesn't work and why this one does. I haven't found any resources that could give an example of this scenario.

```swift
struct PartnerDetailView: View {
    @Binding var partner: Partner

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section("Locations") {
                List($partner.locations, id: \.self) { $location in
                    NavigationLink {
                        LocationDetailView(partner: $partner, locationIndex: partner.locations.firstIndex(of: location) ?? 0)
                    } label: {
                        Text(location.name)
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

```swift
struct LocationDetailView: View {
    @Binding var partner: Partner
    var locationIndex: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Name", text: $partner.locations[locationIndex].name)
    }
}
```

Is it possible that I am not passing values between views properly?

[image]

Comment: Using an `index` in a SwiftUI `ForEach` is a code smell. Which one is the workaround?  Using the index or the first code block?

Comment: @Paulw11 Using the index is the workaround and yes I know it is a code smell but it really concerns me.

Comment: Do you have a lot of fields to edit in LocationDetailView, if not maybe skip the navigation link and edit them directly in the list in PartnerDetailView.